# Links to same page causing page to jump - but only when I add it into magento

Tags: css, magento

So I am developing a page for a client that has an accordion (pure css) on it.

It works fine, but when I add it into magento (a CMS I have never used before) everything works, but when you click the link to open the accordion, it jumps that section to the top of the page.

Here's the html:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <ul>

    <li ><a href="#one">CHICKEN MARINADES</a>
      <div id="one" class="accordion">

jdv[oifdj

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#two">PORK MARINADES</a>
      <div id="two" class="accordion">
       dpifhd[foivh
      </div>
    </li>    
    <li>
      <a href="#three">BEEF MARINADES</a>
      <div id="three" class="accordion">
        gfspiuqdhsv;
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the css:

```
#accordion{margin:10px auto; max-width:600px;}
#accordion ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
.accordion{display:none;}
.accordion:target{display:block;}
#accordion ul li a{text-decoration:none;display:block;padding:2px;}
.accordion{padding:4px;}

/*  Colors 
====================*/
#accordion ul{
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:0 4px 10px #BDBDBD;
   -moz-box-shadow:0 4px 10px #BDBDBD;
        box-shadow:0 4px 10px #BDBDBD;
/*border-radius*/
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
   -moz-border-radius:5px;
        border-radius:5px;
}
#accordion ul li a{
background:#fff;

color:#999;
}
.accordion{
background:#fdfdfd;
color:#999;
}
```

Does anyone know how to stop this happening in magenta?

*****EDIT*****
Forgot to mention, there is no JS (at the moment - but I'm open to it!)

Comment: I would suggest the JS needs to return false or preventDefault on the event.  Could you show the JS?

Comment: @DouglasRadburn Thanks. There is currently no javascript... It's css only. Iwondered if JS would do it, but I'm afraid I don't know it well enough! My googling did throw up return false and preventDefault, but I can't work out how to implement them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with this line:

```
.accordion:target{display:block;}
```

even when I tried to use JS to stop the page jumping it messed other things up.

I've implemented an entirely new accordion that uses JS and that has sorted it!